# Is there a way to conume Redis MONITOR data in ServiceStack Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack

Does ServiceStack.Redis have the ability to call the Redis Monitor command and consume it's data, similiar to [node-redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) client?:

```
var client  = require("redis").createClient(),
    util = require("util");

client.monitor(function (err, res) {
    console.log("Entering monitoring mode.");
});

client.on("monitor", function (time, args) {
    console.log(time + ": " + util.inspect(args));
});
```

I checked the [IRedisNativeClient Interface](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisNativeClient) but didn't see a method for the monitor command.

Answer (score 0):

No-one has added the Monitor command to [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) yet as it's not something you would typically use inside an application. i.e. the normal use-case would be to monitor the redis commands using `redis-cli` possibly piped through unix commands to grep the output.

At the same time, we would still welcome a pull-request to add support for this.